# Admin: how to make a custom list filter button send GET queryvars

Tags: filters, admin, actions, columns

I've setted custom columns for a custom post type, and I want to add a filtering functionality. I need to use custom data, so I can't take advantage from things like wp_dropdown_categories and the like.

My current code:

```
// add select
function add_filter_by_macroarea() {
    global $typenow;
    $post_type = 'distributor';
    $macroaree = array('italy','france','spain','world');

    if($typenow == $post_type) {
      $html = '<select id="filter-by-macroarea" name="macroarea">';

      foreach($macroaree as $macroarea){
        $html .= '<option value="' . $macroarea . '">' . $macroarea . '</option>';
      }

      $html .= '</select>';
      echo $html;
    };
}

add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'add_filter_by_macroarea');



// add filtered contents
function convert_id_to_term_in_query($query){
  global $pagenow;
  $post_type = 'distributor';
  $q_vars = &$query->query_vars; // stop, not finished
  var_dump($q_vars); // just to see query vars, not already setted 

} 

add_filter('parse_query', 'convert_id_to_term_in_query');
```

Now, I'm at the point I need to read a custom GET queryvar, the filter selection. Say it's called 'macroarea' and the values should be 'italy', 'france', 'spain' or'world'.

My issue is: how can I pass such a custom queryvar?

Comment: You should be able to access the selected option in `$_GET['macroarea']`, can you try it?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I was fooled by thinking I would found that queryvar in the WP_Query object ($query). I'm giung to post all the relevant code for people.

Comment: If you can post as an answer and then accept your own answer, that helps keep the site tidy with your question showing as resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @cybmeta I was able to solve my issue. Below I post all the relevant code. Keep in mind it refers to a 'distributor' custom post type that uses 4 custom taxonomies ('italy','france','spain','world').

```
// add columns
function add_distributor_columns($table_columns){
  $area_column = array('area' => 'Area');
  $macroarea_column = array('macroarea' => 'Macroarea');
  // put them on the right position
  $table_columns = array_slice($table_columns, 0, 2, true) + $area_column + $macroarea_column + array_slice($table_columns, 2, NULL, true);
  return $table_columns;
}

add_filter('manage_distributor_posts_columns', 'add_distributor_columns', 10);


// add contents to columns
function add_contents_to_distributor_columns($column_name, $id){
  global $post;
  $post_id = $post->ID;

  if($column_name == 'area'){
    $italy_areas = (array) get_the_terms($post_id,'italy');
    $france_areas = (array) get_the_terms($post_id,'france');
    $spain_areas = (array) get_the_terms($post_id,'spain');
    $world_areas = (array) get_the_terms($post_id,'world');

    $areas = $italy_areas + $france_areas + $spain_areas + $world_areas;

    if(!empty($areas) && $areas[0] !== false){
      $areas_names = array();

      foreach($areas as $area){
        $area_name = $area->name;
        $areas_names[] = $area_name;
      }

      echo implode(', ',$areas_names);
    }
  }//end if

  if($column_name == 'macroarea'){
    $macroareas = array();

    if(has_taxonomy('italy', $post_id)) $macroareas[] = 'Italia';
    if(has_taxonomy('france', $post_id)) $macroareas[] = 'Francia';
    if(has_taxonomy('spain', $post_id)) $macroareas[] = 'Spagna';
    if(has_taxonomy('world', $post_id)) $macroareas[] = 'Mondo';

    if(!empty($macroareas)) echo implode(', ',$macroareas);
  }//end if

}// add_contents_to_distributor_columns

add_action('manage_distributor_posts_custom_column', 'add_contents_to_distributor_columns', 10, 2);


// add macroarea filter
function add_filter_by_macroarea() {
    global $typenow;
    $post_type = 'distributor';
    $macroaree = array('all','italy','france','spain','world');
    $selected = isset($_GET['macroarea']) ? $_GET['macroarea'] : '';

    if($typenow == $post_type) {
      $html = '<select id="filter-by-macroarea" name="macroarea">';

      foreach($macroaree as $macroarea){
        $s = ($macroarea == $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $html .= '<option value="' . $macroarea . '"' . $s . '>' . $macroarea . '</option>';
      }

      echo $html .= '</select>';
    };
}

add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'add_filter_by_macroarea');



// add contents to filtered list
function convert_id_to_term_in_query($query){
  global $pagenow, $post_type;

  if($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'distributor'){
    $selected = isset($_GET['macroarea']) ? $_GET['macroarea'] : null;

    if($selected && $selected != 'all'){
      $terms_ids = wp_list_pluck(get_terms($selected), 'term_id');

      $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $selected,
          'field' => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => $terms_ids,
        )
      );
    }// if selected
  }// if right page
}// end filter

add_filter('parse_query', 'convert_id_to_term_in_query');



// UTILITY FUNCTIONS ---------- //

function get_taxonomies_info($post_id = null){
  if(!$post_id){ // if not passed, try to get the ID
    global $wp_query;
    $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();//current post id
  }

  global $wpdb;
  return $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
      select tax.taxonomy as taxonomy, group_concat(tr.name) as term_names, group_concat(tr.term_id) as term_ids
      from " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy tax
      INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships rel ON tax.term_taxonomy_id =rel.term_taxonomy_id
      INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms tr ON tr.term_id = tax.term_id
      WHERE rel.object_id = %d
      GROUP BY taxonomy
  ",$post_id),OBJECT_K);
}

function has_taxonomy($taxonomy_slug, $post_id = null){
  if(!$post_id){// if not passed, try to get the ID
    global $wp_query;
    $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();//current post id
  }

  return array_key_exists($taxonomy_slug, get_taxonomies_info($post_id));
}
```